# How to call methods from viewcontroller onto skscene

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I have tried to call a method in a viewcontroller after a specified action in the GameScene class in spritekit but to no avail. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could post an example of calling a simple method from inside the viewcontroller class (that's linked to the skscene) in the skscene class.

I would greatly appreciate any answers!

Comment: check out my answer for this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184461/how-to-call-method-from-viewcontroller-in-gamescene/28187085#28187085

Comment: I have tried that but it would not let me call the method on the variable declared in skscene 'viewcontroller'. So it basically would not let me do 'viewcontroller.gameOver()'

Comment: Post some code because I'm having trouble understanding where the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a question of referencing your viewController in your GameScene.
There are many approaches, one is to use this in the GameScene:

```
let controller = self.view?.window?.rootViewController as GameViewController
```

Now this will return the viewController that is showing the scene at that moment. So if you have more then one controller, you should take care with this.

Comment: Can I attached a method name found in the root viewcontroller using dot syntax after the constant 'controller'?

Comment: Yes, you should have access to all the methods in the viewController as long as the trailing `as Something` references the particular Type of your game view controller. So if you didn't change that part, the code here should reference it nicely, I just tried it ;)