# UIImagePickerController in Spritekit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3

I am trying to import an image into a Spritekit scene. Using Xcode version 8.2 (8C38) with Swift 3. The code below work fine in a single view application but not with Spritekit.

```
    class GameScene: SKScene, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

getting the following error

```
    GameScene.swift:93:9: Use of unresolved identifier 'present'
```

cannot find 'present' under self or self.view either, i know in previous versions of swift we use to have presentViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't invoke `present` on a `GameScene` object.

Instead you need to invoke present on a reference to `GameViewController`.

And you can find the instructions to retrieve a reference to your `GameViewController` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28187085/1761687).